# Ember 1.13.x and newer version relation with jquery

Tags: jquery, ember.js

1. Does Ember require jquery to be imported in older or newer versions ?
2. if yes, will older ember support if newer version of jquery.js file is included ? any docs to
   refer ?
3. what does Ember.$ mean ? does ember have inbuilt jquery ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Ember require jquery to be imported in older or newer versions ?

Starting with the [Edition](https://emberjs.com/editions/), [Octane](https://emberjs.com/editions/octane/) (December 2019), jQuery is not shipped with ember by default. And throughout the 3.x series, jQuery was not needed (about since Feb 2018 (about 3 years ago)).

So, prior to Octane, Ember shipped with jQuery by default.

Ember 1.13 is from July of *2015*, so ~ 6+ years ago. And this is definitely before Ember Octane, so jQuery is included.

jQuery was removed from Ember because the majority of jQuery's features are natively implemented by browsers now, and Ember doesn't need to ship that extra JS to every app (which speeds everyone's apps up via jQuery's removal)

> if yes, will older ember support if newer version of jquery.js file is included ? any docs to refer ?

older ember is not supported at all, so you'd kinda be on your own. As long as jQuery's public API hasn't changed, I imagine things would work no problem.

> what does Ember.$ mean ? does ember have inbuilt jquery ?

yeah, it's just an alias. the implementation is literally:

```js
Ember.$ = window.jQuery;
```